Drawing a quadruple arrow
I have this code for drawing single, double and triple arrows using tikz. It works nicely. But somehow it does not work for quadruple arrows (i.e. arrows with one arrow head but four lines). Can someone help me?
Here's a MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Define custom arrow styles
\tikzset{
    singlearrow/.style={->, >=latex, line width=0.15mm, shorten >=1pt},
    doublearrow/.style={
        line width=0.15mm,
        draw, ->, >=latex,
        double distance=0.4mm,
        shorten >=1pt
    },
    triplearrow/.style={
        line width=0.15mm,
        draw, ->, >=latex,
        double distance=0.8mm,
        shorten >=1pt,
        postaction={draw[line width=0.15mm, ->, >=latex, xshift=0mm, yshift=-0.4mm]},
        >={Latex[length=5pt, width=4pt]} % Larger arrowhead for triple arrow
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Single arrow
    \draw[singlearrow] (0,0) -- (2,0) node[midway, above] {Single Arrow};
    
    % Double arrow
    \draw[doublearrow] (0,-1) -- (2,-1) node[midway, above] {Double Arrow};
    
    % Triple arrow
    \draw[triplearrow] (0,-2) -- (2,-2) node[midway, above] {Triple Arrow};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Your example does not seem to compile.

draw[…] is not correct syntax. The argument to postaction are just normal TikZ keys, say draw, ….

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
arrow/.style={>=Latex, shorten >=1pt},
singlearrow/.style={arrow, ->},
doublearrow/.style={arrow, ->, double distance between line centers=0.5mm},
triplearrow/.style={arrow, ->, double distance between line centers=1.0mm, postaction={draw, -, shorten >=2mm}},
quadruplearrow/.style={arrow, -{>[scale=1.5]}, double distance between line centers=0.5mm, preaction={draw, -, thin, shorten >=3mm, double distance between line centers=1.5mm}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[singlearrow] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[midway, above] {Single Arrow};
\draw[doublearrow] (0,-1) -- (4,-1) node[midway, above] {Double Arrow};
\draw[triplearrow] (0,-2) -- (4,-2) node[midway, above] {Triple Arrow};
\draw[quadruplearrow] (0,-3) -- (4,-3) node[midway, above] {Quadruple Arrow};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you very much! Can you also add a line for quintuple arrows?

quintuplearrow/.style={arrow, -{>[scale=1.5]}, double distance between line centers=1.0mm, preaction={draw, -, thin, shorten >=4mm, double distance between line centers=2.0mm}, postaction={draw,-, shorten >=2mm}},

You should look into the nfold package instead of this. -it can draw multiple lines also as curves and with transparent(instead of white as here) spacing between lines.
